# Python package wheel PKG-INFO name

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-wheel

I followed [Packaging and Distributing Projects](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi) to create a Python package to upload to Artifactory. In my `setup.py`, I specified `name='foo_bar'` and then I ran `python setup.py bdist_wheel`. I noticed that in `egg-info\PKG-INFO`, `name` got changed to `foo-bar`. This also determines the package folder name on Artifactory upon upload. However, I like to keep it the same as what I specified in `setup.py`, any idea why this is happening? It seems like `bdist_wheel` automatically converted `_` to `-`.

Comment: this transformation seems to thwart internal pypi searches, eg
`dependency_links=["https://pypi.company_foo.com/package_with_underscores"]`. Also thwarts static analysis tools tracing the package name literals in `setuptools.setup( name="package_with_underscores",`

Answer (score 1):

According to [PEP 0426 -- Metadata for Python Software Packages 2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/#name), both hyphen and underscore are legal characters for name. However, it also says the following:

*All comparisons of distribution names... MUST consider hyphens and underscores to be equivalent.*

This doesn't really answer your question as to why it is being changed, but it does at least assure you that the name should be treated as equivalent either way.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the package name has changed to `foo-bar`, you can still import it using.
`import foo_bar`